# How to serialize arguments array into a string for ProcessStartInfo available in .NET Standard 2.0?

Tags: c#, .net-5, .net-standard-2.0

There is a nice `ArgumentsList` property of `ProcessStartInfo` in .NET 5.0, but when I target my library to .NET Standard 2.0 I don't have it available, so I must convert the arguments manually.

Obviously, arguments can contain spaces and they are also delimited by spaces. So I guess I should use quotes, but then quote the quotes that might appear in arguments, it is all probably pretty platform specific.

Is there a tool for that accessible in .NET Standard 2.0?
If not, what should my conversion do exactly?

I know it should add double quotes on arguments containing spaces.
It also should escape double quotes with double double quotes.
I figured it out by trying following command line in Debug panel of project properties in Visual Studio:

```
arg1 "arg 2" "arg ""3"""
```

When the app started, main function obtained following arguments:

"arg1", "arg 2", and "arg "3"". So it seems like that should work, but I'm not completely sure if that's all that should be considered.

I also wonder - will it work on Linux? Is the conversion for Linux done in the same way, or differently?

**UPDATE**:
I've checked the .NET sources... and...

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6d707d78c87c6c619d48537dff0568696a5d65bd/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/PasteArguments.Unix.cs#L9

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6d707d78c87c6c619d48537dff0568696a5d65bd/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/PasteArguments.Windows.cs#L9

https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/6d707d78c87c6c619d48537dff0568696a5d65bd/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/PasteArguments.cs#L10

The only difference I see is "No way to get a literal quote past the parser." - as a rule for Windows, and quotes parsed normally with double quotes on Unix version. And this is what I found is made with the command line when testing on my Visual Studio on Windows.

As I only need to create command lines for `ProcessStartInfo` and not parse them into argument collections - it's perfectly safe if I take quoting rules mentioned before - so translate any double quote to double double quote and add double quotes to all arguments containing spaces. It should work on both systems and might possibly fail on some very, very specific cases that would not be possible in my library and use case anyway. My library is a class wrapper for a command line tool, BTW, the command line tool AFAIK exists only on Windows.

However, the class is intended to be possible to exist in Linux version, but its `IsSupported` property returns false on Linux. So whatever the lib does should be handled by another tool on Linux platform. The goal is to allow different implementations in ONE program, depending on OS it is run on.

Comment: The startinfo is the command line string (in a console  window) and the program reads in the arguments in main : string[] args.  Windows and linux pass the arguements into an exe very similar but not exactly the same.  It been a long time since I've run run a c language app on linux and had to make slight changes in code to a handle both command line parameters to work in bothy windows and linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
public static class ProcessExtensions {

    public static void SetArguments(this ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo, IEnumerable<string> args) {
        processStartInfo.Arguments = String.Join(" ", args.Select(arg => {
            if (arg.Contains('"')) arg = arg.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
            if (arg.Contains(' ')) arg = '"' + arg + '"';
            return arg;
        }));
    }
}
```

Here's my quick solution, but maybe you can figure out something better. I know, `args` is not null tested. However the project is marked as `nullable`, so `IEnumerable<string>` instead of `IEnumerable<string?>?` implies args must not be null and VS will mark all possibilities of null argument as warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I have started with answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66874537/3224237 but it did not work for me on a Linux system when the argument does contain single quotes (`'`). What works for me in all cases is

```cs
public static string MakeArguments(IEnumerable<string> args)
{
    return String.Join(" ", args.Select(arg =>
    {
        if (arg.Contains('\'')) arg = arg.Replace("'", "'\"'\"'");
        arg = '\'' + arg + '\'';
        return arg;
    }));
}
```

Note that intentionally *every* argument is surrounded by single quotes to not miss a test for a character which would require an escape. Note also that the sequence `'"'"'` is interpreted as `'` in a string surrounded by single quotes.